# Deploy platform-independent war on IBM Websphere V7

Tags: web-applications, websphere, jax-ws, web.xml

Maybe someone can shed light on the mysterious behavior of the  tag in web.xml file in a War application – when it was deployed on WAS v7.

In short, we have a War application that publishes JAX-WS web services. 
The web.xml is using  “WSServletContextListener”, and “WSServlet” in order to provide web-services platform independent deployment.  The published web services are consumed by a client we built using Delphi (XE)
The idea works well with Java EE servers like weblogic, Tomcat, JBoss, etc.

Problem was, that, when deployed on WAS V7, the WSDL (that was published successfully) presented a little different WSDL than the other Java EE servers. 
The auto-created "<xsd:import   >" tag in the WSDL was changed from the URL path that the client can decipher to file based path that cannot be decipher by our client program.
I managed to fix this WAS behavior only when I degraded the web.xml   from version 2.5 to version 2.4.

Does anyone knows what might be the problem?

Comment: Describe "file-based path". I find it extremely hard to believe that the URL began with `file:`. Can you provide us with the `xsd:import` line provided in 2.4 and 2.5, so we can see the difference?